# Referencing external private Git repository in CircleCi build

Tags: python, git, github, continuous-integration, circleci

Here is the scenario I am dealing with:

1. I WANT to/HAVE setup CircleCI build for my project with unit tests etc.
2. In this project I use another one of my libraries which needs to be installed on the build container in CirleCi, otherwise my tests are failing.

I need to find a way to either:

1. pull git repository of external reference and install it
2. Or download it as zip
3. Or some other way ?

Happy to add more explanation if needed.

Answer (score 2):

From the section [Using Resources External to Your Repository](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/external-resources/):

- CircleCI supports `git submodule`, and has advanced SSH key management to let you access multiple repositories from a single test suite. From your project’s Project Settings > Checkout SSH keys page, you can add a “user key” with one-click, allowing you access code from multiple repositories in your test suite. Git submodules can be easily set up in your circle.yml file (see example 1).
- CircleCI’s VMs are connected to the internet. You can download dependencies directly while setting up your project, using `curl` or `wget`.

(Or just using `git clone` without submodules.)

Comment: Ended up using `git submodule` and would definitely endorse it.